# Prettier only changes double quotes to single quotes in .tsx files, but not .ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, create-react-app, prettier

When I try to auto-format my VS Code with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[I] it corrects my double-quotes "" to single-quotes '' in *.tsx files. But when I try the same in *.ts files nothing happens.

I have both in my Settings > Extensions > Prettier

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
"prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true
```

And I have in my `.prettierrc`

```
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true
```

Comment: Make sure prettier is the default formatter with `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up Prettier in VSCode settings to conditionally apply single quotes by file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759602/how-can-i-set-up-prettier-in-vscode-settings-to-conditionally-apply-single-quote)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following `overrides` in your `.prettierrc`:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts"],
      "options": {
        "singleQuote": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60256420/4576650) answer.

Comment: If it is taken from another Stack Overflow question, it is then a duplicate.

Comment: Got it, sorry, (almost) first time poster, long time user. Question should be marked as duplicate then.

Comment: That's fine - I've already marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: This does not seem relevant to the poster's question. He was not asking how to turn off singleQuotes for .ts files, but rather how to consistently correct double quotes to single quotes across both .tsx and .ts files.